# How do I safely store suspected SQL injection attacks in a database?

Tags: php, sql-injection

How would I go about storing potential SQL injection attacks in a database?

Assume first that I have detected a potential attack, and have the offending attack string in a variable and would like to add it to a table containing a log of suspicious events.

What would I need to do to safely insert these strings into a database so that no errors would be produced?

I have a feeling that it will be something along the lines of htmlspecialchars and mysql_real_escape_string... but I wanted to throw it out there to see if anybody else had any ideas!

One thought was to store the attack as an encoded base64 value, but that seems a bit hackish...

FYI, I am writing the application in PHP :)

Any responses would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're storing attacks in a database, then what is wrong with base64? It's not "hackish", it makes it safe to store.

Comment: Strictly from a personal standpoint, I'd save it in a file on the server (with a reference to the file in the DB). I navigate the ftp at least daily, making it easy to check a file or two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use parameterized queries.  If you are using parameters, you don't need to rely on escaping strings and your query will always do exactly what you intend.

e.g.:

```
$statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table_name (field_name1, field_name2) VALUES (:value, :value2)');
$statement->execute(array(':value' => $value, ':value2' => $value2));
```

See documentation for PDO prepare here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 2):

Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) prepared statements to store the queries, it's the safest method to avoid sql injection. If you're going to display them via a web interface and concerned about XSS/CSRF attacks, use `htmlspecialchars()` before displaying them.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you are storing any other data.
There is nothing special in storing SQL injection attacks, whatever you call it.

Answer (score 0):

Like Steve Mayne said ... please use php PDO connection with prepared statements. It's the safes right now . Don't user mysql_connect() and subfunctions anymore because it's old and you cannot fully benefit of new mysql / sql / etc .. funcitons .

Answer (score -1):

All I would do is run it though a simple encryption.
Then when you want to show the suspected sql, you would just decrypt it.
This should insure the suspected sql statement does not get executed on your db.

Comment: Encryption is overkill, properly escaping strings or using prepared statements is enough.

Comment: Exception an attacker who knows the encryption used might be able construct a statement whose *encrypted* form performs SQL injection. This is really the wrong way to address the problem.

Comment: I didn't say it would be the best way to do it, or the most secure but you could also say that escaping strings is also a form of encryption, you are taking the original, changing it, and saving the result.

Comment: Escaping strings is a form of *encoding*.  Encryption and encoding are two different things.  Encoding is meant for making data safe for storage and/or transport.  Encryption, not so much -- the encrypted data can be just as dangerous as the plaintext, sometimes even more so depending on the scheme used. It's just less readable to strangers, which isn't necessary here.